# How to create a power bar in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to create a power bar which will toggle automatically up and down and will stop when i click on the screen.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please review [ask]. It appears that you forgot to actually ask a question, and instead posted a work request. Please rephrase your question to include [what you've tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com) and be sure to actually ask a question about the part that you're struggling with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to be more specific about what exactly you have tried and what is not working.  However, this should get you started.  This example uses **sgv** but could easily be translated into a more **div** oriented approach.

The objective is to hit the *toggle* button when the circle is in the center region.  Good Luck!

**Note:** This might only work in chrome at the moment.

```js
document.getElementById("toggler").addEventListener("click", function(){
  var el = document.querySelector("circle");
  var className = "stopped";

  el.classList.toggle(className);

  if (!el.classList.contains(className)) { return }

  var currentCX = parseFloat(getComputedStyle(el).getPropertyValue("cx"));

  if (currentCX >= 240 && currentCX <= 260 ) {
    console.log("hit");
  } else {
    console.log("miss");
  }
});
```

```css
@keyframes sweep {
  from { cx: 5; }
  to { cx: 495; }
}

circle{
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-name: sweep;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;  
  animation-direction: alternate;
}

circle.stopped{
  animation-play-state: paused;
}
```

```html
<svg id="lineWithDots" width="500px" height="20px">
  <g transform="translate(0,10)">
    <rect width="490" height="2" y="-1" x="5" />
    <rect width="20" height="10" y="-5" x="240" />
    <circle r="4" cx="5" stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)" fill="rgb(255, 255, 255)" />
  </g>
</svg>

<div>
  <button id="toggler">toggle</button>
</div>
```